# anguarljs, ng-repeat, how can i assign the output of the function to a variable and use this variable in the current loop

Tags: angularjs

I have the following data:

```
$scope.AcctHistList = "[{"AcctHistID":13,"AcctID":6,"TranAmount":444,"TranDSC":"IncomeBill","UserDSC":"423142341","TXID":"ec9a8fb7-9f76-4671-f7c7-75a77c2a7a04","Created_D":"2015-09-14","Created_T":"08:00","Created_DT":"2015-09-14 08:00","Created_YM":"2015-09","Created_W":"37","Created_Y":"2015","Created_w":"Mo","AcctCurrency":"AED"}
                            ,{"AcctHistID":12,"AcctID":6,"TranAmount":444,"TranDSC":"IncomeBill","UserDSC":"undefined","TXID":"eaec26e6-4dc1-41a3-e987-d27843cefed8","Created_D":"2015-09-14","Created_T":"08:00","Created_DT":"2015-09-14 08:00","Created_YM":"2015-09","Created_W":"37","Created_Y":"2015","Created_w":"Mo","AcctCurrency":"AED"}
                            ,{"AcctHistID":11,"AcctID":6,"TranAmount":444,"TranDSC":"IncomeBill","UserDSC":"undefined","TXID":"16a323b3-0f11-4a18-e753-e4f262ace2ca","Created_D":"2015-09-14","Created_T":"08:00","Created_DT":"2015-09-14 08:00","Created_YM":"2015-09","Created_W":"37","Created_Y":"2015","Created_w":"Mo","AcctCurrency":"AED"}
                            ,{"AcctHistID":10,"AcctID":6,"TranAmount":44,"TranDSC":"IncomeBill","UserDSC":"423141234","TXID":"bc5b4a80-0322-4e04-9bb4-5a82973c99a7","Created_D":"2015-10-11","Created_T":"09:12","Created_DT":"2015-10-11 09:12","Created_YM":"2015-10","Created_W":"40","Created_Y":"2015","Created_w":"Su","AcctCurrency":"AED"}
                            ,{"AcctHistID":9,"AcctID":6,"TranAmount":44,"TranDSC":"IncomeBill","UserDSC":"423141234","TXID":"e8ba0ec2-e007-4925-94af-7cc038937aa3","Created_D":"2015-10-11","Created_T":"09:12","Created_DT":"2015-10-11 09:12","Created_YM":"2015-10","Created_W":"40","Created_Y":"2015","Created_w":"Su","AcctCurrency":"AED"}
                            ,{"AcctHistID":8,"AcctID":6,"TranAmount":44,"TranDSC":"IncomeBill","UserDSC":"423141234","TXID":"d516756f-afc6-454b-c7d1-db55c474397f","Created_D":"2015-10-11","Created_T":"09:12","Created_DT":"2015-10-11 09:12","Created_YM":"2015-10","Created_W":"40","Created_Y":"2015","Created_w":"Su","AcctCurrency":"AED"}
                            ]"
```

in the view i iterate through these data and group it using the user input(Day,Month,Week,Year,...).

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="group in AcctHistList | groupBy:AcctHistGropuBy | toArray:true |  orderBy:'-$key'">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <strong data-i18n={{group.$key}}>{{group.$key}}</strong>
    <span class="label pull-right" ng-model="SumAmount = SumTranAmount(group)">
        <span class="badge">{{SumAmount.In}}</span>
        <span class="badge">-{{SumAmount.Out}}</span>
        <span class="badge">={{SumAmount.Total}}{{SumAmount.Currency}}</span>
    </span>
</div>

 <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-i18n={{item.TranDSC}}>
                {{item.TranDSC}}
            </h4>
            <span class="badge">{{item.Created_DT}}</span>
            <span class="badge">{{item.TranAmount}} {{item.AcctCurrency}}</span>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">{{item.UserDSC}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The main problem is that, i want to summarize each group (to calculate TotalIn, TotalOut, and In-Out), So i wrote the function SumTranAmount for this.

```
$scope.SumTranAmount = function (group) {
    var Total = 0, In = 0, Out = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        Total = Total + group[i].TranAmount
        if (group[i].TranAmount >= 0) {
            In = In + group[i].TranAmount;
        }
        else {
            Out = Out - group[i].TranAmount;
        }
    }
    //return (In + " " + Out + " = " + Total + " " + group[0].AcctCurrency);
    return { In: In, Out: Out, Total: Total, Currency: group[0].AcctCurrency };
}
```

Problem, an exception occured `ng-model="SumAmount = SumTranAmount(group)"`

So, my question is, how can i assign the output of the function to a variable and use this variable in the current loop??

Comment: I think you are looking for something like ng-init: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Thank you, it worked successfully.